# Want to Store SQLite Database Permanently

Tags: database, sqlite

Now, I am developing one web application and create,insert and select every query is did by JavaScript and I have large size of SQLite database. I want to store my database permanently. But when i clear the browser history entire database get loss. Now, I need a solution. Is there any way to rectify this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, it is only limited by file size / disk space.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every database in SQLite consists of one or more "pages". Within a single database, every page is the same size, but different database can have page sizes that are powers of two between 512 and 65536, inclusive. The maximum size of a database file is 2147483646 pages. At the maximum page size of 65536 bytes, this translates into a maximum database size of approximately 1.4e+14 bytes (140 terabytes, or 128 tebibytes, or 140,000 gigabytes or 128,000 gibibytes).

This particular upper bound is untested since the developers do not have access to hardware capable of reaching this limit. However, tests do verify that SQLite behaves correctly and sanely when a database reaches the maximum file size of the underlying filesystem (which is usually much less than the maximum theoretical database size) and when a database is unable to grow due to disk space exhaustion.